# Problems creating a ComposerServiceProvider in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.4

Im working on a Laravel 5 app and im trying to set up a ComposerServiceProvider to pass data to a couple of views (im trying now to add it to the layout/app.blade.php).
I did this following the documentation but the data im trying to add is still undefined..

In my **config/app.php** I added to the providers:

```
App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

On **ComposerServiceProvider.php** 
**boot** method:

```
View::composer(['layouts.app'], 'App\ViewComposers\LayoutAppComposer');
```

On the new created **LayoutAppComposer.php**
**compose(View $view)** method:

```
$metaTitle = 'MetaTitle';
    $view->with('metaTitle', $metaTitle)
```

But When i access the url I still get:

```
Undefined variable: metaTitle (View: .../resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)
```

Am I missing something here??

**ServiceProvider**

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;


class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        View::composer(['layouts.app'], 'App\ViewComposers\LayoutAppComposer');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

**LayoutAppComposer**

```
<?php

namespace App\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class LayoutAppComposer {

    protected $metaTitle;

    public function __construct($metaTitle)
    {
        $this->metaTitle = $metaTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Bind data to the view.
     *
     * @param  View  $view
     * @return void
     */
    public function compose(View $view) {
        $this->metaTitle = 'MetaTitle';
        $view->with('metaTitle', $this->metaTitle);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok I think I know now, what are you binding metaTitle to? When the service providers are resolved, they will use dependency injection to create a $metaTitle for your constructor. You may need to bind it in your AppServiceProvider, otherwise it will be null.

Comment: if i understood you correctly i should add this to AppServiceProvider right?

$this->app->bind(
            'App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider'
);


if thats it, im still getting the error :S

Comment: No I actually think the problem is $metaTitle is null when it's passed to LayoutAppComposer's constructor. What did you intend to set as metaTile's value anyways?

Comment: Oh so what should i bind in AppServiceProvider? sorry didnt underrstand that part.
About your question, actually im just setting a string here, but im doing this now to learn since i will need to add a more complex variable next.

Comment: Check my answer edit.

Comment: Tryied that but still not working.
But i noticed something, if i add the code of ComposerServiceProvider in AppServiceProvider boot method it kind of works.. So te problem seems to be that the composerServiceProvider is not recognized.
Im going to work wit the AppServiceProvider for the moment, but this is strange XD

Comment: Try registering the composer with a different view file, I'm wondering if the layouts.app is throwing it off. All the examples I've seen have a single file name in there like 'index', which resolves to index.blade.php

View::composer('index', 'App\ViewComposers\LayoutAppComposer');

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
$metaTitle = 'MetaTitle';
$view->with('metaTitle', $metaTitle)
```

to

```
$this->metaTitle = 'metaTitle';
$view->with('metaTitle', $this->metaTitle)
```

setup `$this->metaTitle` as a protected class member and assign it in the composer constructor. it may be that $metaTitle is getting garbage collected before you use it since this being resolved at the service provider level.

Since you're registering the composer with your app layout, instead you may need to use the wildcard character in place of app.layout like such:

```
View::composer('*', function ($view) {
    //
});
```

To resolve $metaTile for the View Composer, try binding in your AppServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->bind('metaTitle', 'the string i want displayed across all views');
```

Comment: Much appreciate the help. But im still getting the same error. IT seems it doesnt use the ComposerServiceProvider. Is there any way to check if its being called? 
I tryied adding a "die()" or var_dump but nothing happened.

Comment: can you post the service provider and composer classes?

Comment: just posted the classes